# Run a continuous task from static main method using tasks?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to introduce async/await into a new codebase to have it do a background task every x seconds.

I've got the following, but it just stalls forever without ever running the action (printStuff).

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ASyncTaskDemo
{
    class Program3
    {    
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Action action = printStuff;    
            ExecuteEvery(new Task(action), 5000).Wait();
            //simulate the rest of the application stalling until shutdown events.
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int x = 0;

        private static void printStuff()
        {
            Console.Error.Write(x++);
        }

        private static async Task ExecuteEvery(Task execute, int milliseconds)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var delay = Task.Delay(milliseconds);
                await Task.WhenAll(delay, execute);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do I make sure that the tasks are running on the right threads, or even running at all?

execute is expected to be a longish running database summary query.
milliseconds is expected to be in the range of seconds to minutes, and would appreciate accuracy in timing.

By 'right threads' I mean that the task should execute in an async/networking context, not synchronously with the main program dispatch.

However there may be times when it would be appropriate to run the task in a UI thread or a server thread if this code is to be reusable, and I would appreciate if it was explained what thread and how to configure it.

Comment: what do you mean by 'running on the right threads'? can you please explain it in detail

Comment: I've added an edit clarifying.

Comment: If your `Action` is going to be a _pure_ `async` call, i.e `i/o` call and not a cpu bound one, then you shouldn't use `Task.Run()`, use the async methods for db provider api etc.

Comment: It was probably something lost whilst anonymizing and minifying the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using a `Func<Task>` instead of a `Action<Task>`

This enables the use of an async method, instead of a function, and allows the other method to be appropriately decorated with the async keyword.

```
/// <summary>
/// Executes a task every x milliseconds, but will wait for long running tasks to complete.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="execute">A Task Producer</param>
/// <param name="milliseconds">How often to run execute</param>
/// <param name="cancel">A cancellation token</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task ExecuteEvery(Func<Task> execute, int milliseconds, CancellationToken cancel)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delay = Task.Delay(milliseconds, cancel);
        await Task.WhenAll(delay, execute());
        if(cancel.IsCancellationRequested) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I've got the following, but it just stalls forever without ever
>   running the action (printStuff).

This happens because the `Task` you passed to executeEvety was created using  the 'Task' constructor, so it will not be scheduled to run if you don't run it explicitly , so by awaiting you wait for an unstarted task to finish - this will never happend.

You should instead pass an `Action` to executeEvery and invoke it every loop iteration without the need of async  invocation:

```
ExecuteEvery(action, 5000).Wait();

private static async Task ExecuteEvery(Action action, int milliseconds)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
        action();
    }
}
```

If the action is long running and. you want to run it in the background without waiting for it to finish before the next iteration (fire and forget), add `Task.Run` when you invoke it:

```
private static async Task ExecuteEvery(Action action, int milliseconds)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
        Task.Run(() => action());
    }
}
```

But wouldn't it be better to just forget about the endless loop and use [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) to achieve what you want?

Comment: This does not run the task every x milliseconds, but runs the task every x milliseconds + potentially long Action.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually start a task. Indeed, IMHO it does not make sense to represent `execute` as a task. Just pass the delegate itself:

```
class Program3
{    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action action = printStuff;    
        ExecuteEvery(action, 5000); // ignore returned task
        //simulate the rest of the application stalling until shutdown events.
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int x = 0;

    private static void printStuff()
    {
        Console.Error.Write(x++);
    }

    private static async Task ExecuteEvery(Action execute, int milliseconds)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(milliseconds);
            execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that if you call `Wait()`, you'll never read the `ReadLine()`. I've removed it in my version above.

Comment: This does not run the task every x milliseconds, but runs the task every x milliseconds + potentially long Action.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach: yup, you are correct. Feel free to use the `Task.WhenAll()` approach if you prefer. It's not a perfect way to address that either...if the task takes longer than the specified delay, you get into ambiguity of whether to try to catch up, overlap actions, etc. which seems outside the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a `Task` does not automatically start it. You're awaiting on a `Task` that will never complete because it is not started. You should start a `Task` using `Task.Run()` I have modified your code a bit below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Action action = printStuff;
    ExecuteEvery(action, 5000).Wait();
    //simulate the rest of the application stalling until shutdown events.
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static int x = 0;

private static void printStuff()
{
    Console.Error.Write(x++);
}

private static async Task ExecuteEvery(Action execute, int milliseconds)
{
    while (true)
    {
        var delay = Task.Delay(milliseconds);
        await Task.WhenAll(delay, Task.Run(execute));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use the passed in Task in the original and run it? 

Does running the task inside the while loop change the timings so that it's no longer every x milliseconds, but x milliseconds + tasktime?

Comment: Though good, I wonder if the calling code should be responsible for calling `Task.Run()` on the `Action`?  Then again, it's probably better to just call the  `Action` directly as others have said :)

Comment: @RyanTheLeach If you pass in the Task, you can call `Start()` on it but will throw exception next iteration when it tries to `Start()` again on a completed `Task`, so it is no good. You will at minimum have to pass the `Action` in too and then recreate the `Task`